# Where are my keys and chain data located if I am using Parity?

Tags: parity, keystore, backup

Switched from geth to Parity and wondering where my information now is. Thanks.

Comment: That's really interesting because I saw your question before, but no one talked about Windows :)

Comment: I know!   I was hoping it would get a good answer that covered all bases.

Comment: This is not properly answered : For windows: $home\AppData\Roaming\Parity\Ethereum\keys\ethereum\* and  for Linux : $home/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/keys/ethereum/*

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In Parity 1.6 : Have a look at

- OSX : `~/Library/Application\ Support/io.parity.ethereum/keys/`
- Linux : `~/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/keys/`
- Windows: `%APPDATA%\Parity\Ethereum\keys`

In Parity 1.5 : Have a look at `~/.parity/keys`. You'll find what you're looking for.

Comment: I installed parity with `bash <(curl https://get.parity.io -Lk)` command on Ubuntu, however I don't have a `~/.parity` folder. Yet it's syncing. Did the default directory change?

Comment: I'm finding my parity data under `~/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/`

Answer (score 11):

When you run `parity -h` you can see the default keystore. It is listed as the default where the `-d --base-path` option is explained, under Operating Options.

On Linux: `~/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/keys/`

On Mac OS: `~/Library/Application\ Support/io.parity.ethereum/keys/`

Comment: This. other answers are incomplete

Answer (score 6):

Parity stores keys in  `~/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/` for linux. Whereas for Windows, it stored them under `C:\Users\{CurrentUser}\.parity\keys`.  `

Comment: This is not correct.  On Windows there is no `$HOME` environment variable (and environment variables are `%` wrapped, not `$` prefixed).  The correct path is `%APPDATA%\Parity\Ethereum\...`, which by _default_ (but not always_ will take you to something like `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Parity\Ethereum\....`

Comment: Also, Parity no longer (incorrectly) stores files in `%USERPROFILE%\.parity` (this was done previously but is really bad form on Windows).

Answer (score 4):

According to the documentation for Parity's [`ethstore`](https://github.com/ethcore/parity/blob/cb9b1e2ad51c2e85eace46529cfefab97fa6c0f6/ethstore/README.md) key management API:

> secret store directory: It may be either parity, parity-test, geth,
>   geth-test or a path. default: parity

(Also of note is the [`ethkey`](https://github.com/ethcore/parity/tree/master/ethkey) key generator API and associated commands.)

Answer (score 4):

When I switched from geth to parity, I noticed that parity imported my accounts from the `.ethereum/keystore/*` directory into parity somehow.

```
0 ✓ user@host ~ $ ll ~/.ethereum/keystore/
total 48K
4.0K drwxr-xr-x 2 user users 4.0K May 13 10:36 .
4.0K drwx------ 9 user users 4.0K Jun 17 10:17 ..
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 user users   58 May 13 10:36 contract-0x1482xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.txt
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 user users   43 Oct 16  2015 contract-0x534cxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.txt
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 user users   43 Oct 16  2015 contract-0xe358xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.txt
4.0K -rw------- 1 user users  491 Oct 16  2015 UTC--2015-10-15T18-13-54.479132678Z--fcaexxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
4.0K -rw------- 1 user users  491 Oct 16  2015 UTC--2015-10-15T20-25-00.928153131Z--a1c2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
4.0K -rw------- 1 user users  491 Jan 15 13:37 UTC--2016-01-15T12-37-23.415253096Z--1337xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
4.0K -rw------- 1 user users  491 Feb  2 01:18 UTC--2016-02-02T00-18-36.894929209Z--a989xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
4.0K -rw------- 1 user users  491 Feb  2 01:36 UTC--2016-02-02T00-36-01.611176405Z--0000xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
4.0K -rw------- 1 user users  491 Feb  4 14:51 UTC--2016-02-04T13-51-18.257136025Z--b195xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
4.0K -rw------- 1 user users  491 Feb  8 12:22 UTC--2016-02-08T11-22-19.471238279Z--006exxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

0 ✓ user@host ~ $ cat .ethereum/keystore/UTC--2016-02-08T11-22-19.471238279Z--006exxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
{"address":"006exxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","crypto":{"cipher":"aes-xxx-xxx","ciphertext":"874axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","cipherparams":{"iv":"fb05xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"},"kdf":"scrypt","kdfparams":{"dklen":xx,"n":xxxxxx,"p":x,"r":x,"salt":"6c6bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"},"mac":"a128xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"},"id":"f433aa7d-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx","version":3}}
```

They are now also located in `.parity/keys/*`:

```
0 ✓ user@host ~ $ ll ~/.parity/keys/
total 36K
4.0K drwxr-xr-x 2 user users 4.0K Apr 20 19:31 .
4.0K drwxr-xr-x 5 user users 4.0K Apr 26 09:58 ..
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 user users  605 Jun 24 10:52 1843f804-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 user users  605 Jun 24 10:52 37dce086-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 user users  605 Jun 24 10:52 52a91bfd-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 user users  605 Jun 24 10:52 8240bdb9-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 user users  605 Jun 24 10:52 af3e6350-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 user users  605 Jun 24 10:52 f433aa7d-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 user users  605 Jun 24 10:52 f4bf9894-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx

0 ✓ user@host ~ $ cat parity/keys/f433aa7d-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx 
{
  "address": "006exxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "crypto": {
    "cipher": "aes-xxx-xxx",
    "cipherparams": {
      "iv": "fb05xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    "ciphertext": "874axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "kdf": "scrypt",
    "kdfparams": {
      "dklen": xx,
      "n": xxxxxx,
      "p": x,
      "r": x,
      "salt": "6c6bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    "mac": "a128xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  },
  "id": "f433aa7d-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "version": 3
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On Windows...

- Private keys are stored in

  ```
     %AppData%\Roaming\Parity\Ethereum\keys\ethereum
  ```
- Blockchain data is stored in

  ```
     %localappdata%\Parity\Ethereum\chains\ethereum\db\<nodeid>\overlayrecent\db
  ```

Comment: The first path is incorrect.  `%APPDATA%` takes you to the `Roaming` folder if you have Windows setup with default paths.  The correct path is `%APPDATA%\Parity\Ethereum\...`

Answer (score 1):

(Just adding to Bob Gill's answer; don't have the reputation to comment).

On Windows, the private keys are in:

```
%appdata%\Parity\Ethereum
```

and Blockchain data is in:

```
%appdata%\..\Local\Parity\Ethereum\chains\ethereum\db\<nodeid>\overlayrecent\db
```

You don't really need to know the "`<nodeid>`"; it's the only folder there unless you have multiple nodes.

(%appdata% points to ...\AppData\Roaming)

Comment: The blockchain data path is wrong.  It should be `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Parity\Ethereum\...`.  `%APPDATA%\..\Local` is not guaranteed to point to the same location as `%LOCALAPPDATA%`, which his where the chain data is _really_ stored.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 7 and 10, I had to go here:

```
C:\Users\{your_user_name}\AppData\Roaming\Parity\Ethereum\keys\ethereum
```

The files that start with `UTC-` are the keys.

Comment: This answer is incorrect as the path up to `AppData\Roaming` may differ depending on your OS settings.  The correct path is `%APPDATA%\Parity\Ethereum\...`