# Parity keystore location on Windows?

Tags: parity

I don't seem to have a parity folder in appdata/roaming called parity. Does anyone know where parity places keys on Windows?

Comment: Is there a way to merge answers onto http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6471/where-are-my-keys-and-chain-data-located-if-i-am-using-parity?