# How to transfer ethereum keys and blockchain to another computer (parity)

Tags: wallets, parity, ubuntu, recovery, backup

I synced the blockchain, using both parity ang ethereum wallet(parity --geth) on an external vps(digital ocean) Now I would like to download everything to a local computer with scp. I found instructions for geth, but not parity. Is this possible? Ubuntu 16.04 on the server and the machine I am transferring to.

Comment: Related: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6471/where-are-my-keys-and-chain-data-located-if-i-am-using-parity

Comment: will try and update both  ~/.parity folder and ~/.ethereum folders on home machine and restart parity --geth from there. thanks