# Parity: accounts from Geth keystore

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, keystore

I am installing the latest version of parity (1.4.1).  I created a new account and am syncing the chain.  I have two UTC keystore files from a older version of geth that I stopped syncing some time ago.

In the parity web gui I click on 'new account' then 'import accounts from geth keystore' but I am told that 'there are currently no importable keys from the Geth keystore, which are not already available on your Parity instance.

These keystore files are in my .ethereum folder and I have also tried copying them and putting them in the .parity/keys directory

Has anyone else has this problem or know how I can import these accounts into parity?

Comment: parity should automatically import your geth keystore entries.

Comment: yes, it "should" but it doesn't on Ubuntu 15

Answer (score 3):

It seems you just copy the keystore file into the /parity/keys directory and reload the gui browser interface and then it will pick up the accounts

Answer (score 1):

Here is the help for Parity:

```
Iota:~ user$ parity --help | grep import-geth
  --import-geth-keys       Attempt to import keys from Geth client.
```

Just run the following command and your `geth` keys will be imported into the Parity keystore:

```
parity --import-geth-keys
```

Answer (score 0):

To add more detail to user, Amazing's  [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/9911/31518):

1. Locate your respective OS's key folder, a good [Guide](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6471/where-are-my-keys-and-chain-data-located-if-i-am-using-parity) on how to do so.
2. Save the keystore file in the folder, the file should look like like this:

> UTC--2015-09-18T14-07-57.023663538Z--da78c8721e4ede42cf488304551eb596dd5f93e23