# Where does web3 store private key?

Tags: web3js

When I use this `web3.personal.importRawKey(pkey, passPhrase);` Where does it store the private key I import? And How can I manually delete it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

web3 doesn't store the key, it sends an RPC request to the node that it is connected to, using the [personal API](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#personal_importrawkey). The node then stores the key in its keystore, encrypted with `passPhrase`.

To delete the key you need to remove it from the node's keystore manually, by deleting the file from the directory. This cannot be done via web3 or RPC commands.

Comment: ah I see ok... Where is the nodes keystore found?

Comment: Depends on the node and OS. Parity: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6471/where-are-my-keys-and-chain-data-located-if-i-am-using-parity    Geth: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/108/how-do-i-backup-my-ether-accounts/109#109